# OpenThread Compiling Errors relating to 'PrefixTlv'

Tags: iar, openthread

I have been asked to take the OpenThread code, compile it, and download it to an SoC (SiLabs - Mighty Gecko). I have added all the files from the src folder and tried to run it through the IAR Embedded Workbench IDE, but receive numerous errors around 'PrefixTlv'. It seems that I am missing a file where this is defined because the most common error reads: Error[Pe020]: identifier "PrefixTlv" is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

There was a merge yesterday that should help with your issue:

https://github.com/openthread/openthread/pull/107

Please try it again with the latest master, and let us know if these new toolchain.h abstractions solve your problems with compiling under IAR.

Comment: Thanks for the response @turon. I moved from Windows to Linux Ubuntu but still get IAR errors so I decided to follow the ‘Getting Started Guide’ with Linux. I can now successfully run the CLI example. I also downloaded the wpantund repository and followed ‘INSTALL.md', but receive errors after ‘sudo /usr/local/sbin/wpantund -o NCPSocketName /dev/ttyACM0’ command:
1. SpinelNCPInstance-Protothreads.cpp:353: Requirement Failed (IS_EVENT_FROM_NCP(event) && GetInstance(this)->mInboundHeader == mLastHeader)
2. SpinelNCPInstance-Protothreads.cpp:343: Requirement Failed (event == EVENT_NCP_RESET)

Comment: I believe my issue is with the Mighty Gecko SoC, probably not initialized with the correct boot code or settings or both. I am able to get sample code to work on the SoC, but I still need a way to get openthread on the board. If I could get the openthread code into a hex or binary file, I know I can get it downloaded to my chip. So to sum up. I feel that the Openthread code is downloaded to my computer, configured, and ready to go, but the issue is with how I have the Mighty Gecko setup (or not setup). Any insight or pointers would be great.

Comment: Hi Chris,
This pull request adds a sample IAR project for cc2538 (Cortex-M3 similar to Gecko): https://github.com/openthread/openthread/pull/190
The top-level workspace to try is in: examples/cc2538/app/cli/proj/iar/openthread-cli.eww